# Calling function with return in class gives TypeError Python

Tags: python-2.7

When I call a function that supposed to return a value, it gives the error `TypeError: 'str'` object is not callable

here is the code:

```
import time
class test:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def data(self):
        return str(self.data)
time.sleep(1)
x = test("data")
print x.data()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self.data` string hides the `data` method. When you try to call `x.data()`, you end up trying to call `"data"()`. Change one of those names.